# Java Servlet and JSP cannot view arraylist from session initially

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I'm a complete beginner to JSPs and servlets and I would appreciate it if you could help me on this small problem. I have an index.html file that has links to two JSP files: addItem.jsp (user can input item into their todDo list, and submit button links to servlet), and toDoList.jsp (shows the toDO list and redirects via a button to addItem.jsp)

The problem I am having is that when I view the toDoList.jsp before adding an item to the list, the list does not appear. However, I add an item on addItem.jsp, the list shows from the servlet, and now I can view the full list, including the item that was added on toDoList.jsp.

How can I change my code so that I don't have to add something to the list to view it?

toDoList.jsp :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpSession" %>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My ToDo List:</h1>

    <% ArrayList<String> toDoList = new ArrayList<String>();%>

    <% if(session.getAttribute("toDoList") != null) {  // If the list exists in the session %>  
    <%   toDoList = (ArrayList<String>) session.getAttribute("toDoList");%> 
    <%   for(String toDoItem:toDoList) { %>
    <%      out.println(toDoItem); %><br>
    <%   } %>
    <% } else {%>

    <h3>Your list is empty!</h3>
    <% } %>
    <form action="addItem.jsp" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Add Item">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
```

addItem.jsp :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="Servlet1" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <label>New ToDo Item:</label>
            <input type="text" name="item"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </fieldset>
    </form>         
</body>
```

The main Servlet1 code:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/Servlet1"})
public class Servlet1 extends HttpServlet {

ArrayList<String> toDoList = new ArrayList<String>();

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    String item = request.getParameter("item");
    toDoList.add(item);

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    boolean is_toDoList_Initilized = false;

    if(session.getAttribute("toDoList") == null) {  
        is_toDoList_Initilized = false;  
        session.setAttribute("toDoList", toDoList);
    } else is_toDoList_Initilized = true;


    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet Servlet1</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        for(String toDoItem:toDoList) { 
            out.println(toDoItem + "<br>");  
        }  
        out.println(is_toDoList_Initilized);
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to call that servlet before redirecting your toDoList.jsp from your index page.

Flow will be like

flow 1: index.jsp > servlet1 > toDoList

flow 2: index.jsp > addItem.jsp > servlet1 > toDoList